# Simple Sales Tax Calculator in jquery using html forms not working

Tags: jquery

This is the first step to an assignment using jQuery. As I understand it the program should attach a function onload to the button press of "calculate". When that button is clicked the processEntries function should execute. processEntries takes the values of id's "subtotal" and "tax_rate", parseFloat them, and assigns them to new variables. Then it calculates the Sales_tax and Total using those variables and spits those variables back out to id's "sales_tax and "total"... But it's not doing that.

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

window.onload = function() {
  $("calculate").onclick = processEntries();
};

function processEntries() {
  var subTotal = parseFloat($("subtotal").value);
  var taxRate = parseFloat($("tax_rate").value);

  if (taxRate > 0) {
    taxRate /= 100;
  }
  var Sales_tax = subTotal * taxRate;

  var Total = subTotal * (taxRate + 1);

  $("sales_tax").value = Sales_tax;
  $("total").value = Total;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <h1>Sales Tax Calculator</h1>
  <p>Enter Subtotal and Tax Rate and click "Calculate".</p>
  <label for="subtotal">Subtotal:</label>
  <input type="text" id="subtotal"><br>

  <label for="tax_rate">Tax Rate:</label>
  <input type="text" id="tax_rate"><br>

  <label for="sales_tax">Sales Tax:</label>
  <input type="text" id="sales_tax" disabled><br>

  <label for="total">Total:</label>
  <input type="text" id="total" disabled><br>

  <label>&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate">
  <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear"><br>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.value` is a vanilla javascript property.  To set the value on a jquery object you would use `.val(newValue)`.  Though `$('sales_tax')` and `$('total')` are also invalid selectors.  You need to put `#` at the start of them to make them id lookups.  Same for the other lookups that are trying to find elements by id.

Comment: Thanks! The actual calculate button still does not function though. Any idea why?

Comment: You're calculate lookup is also invalid and needs to be fixed with the missing `#`.  `onclick` is also a vanilla javascript property.  For jQuery you would use `.on('click', eventHandler)`

Answer (score 0):

There are few basic mistakes with code.

To select a element with id you need to use jquery selector as $('#yourid');

and to assign any value to it use val() method of jquery.

```
window.onload = function() {
      $("#calculate").on('click', processEntries);
    };

    function processEntries() {
      var subTotal = parseFloat($("#subtotal").val());
      var taxRate = parseFloat($("#tax_rate").val());

      if (taxRate > 0) {
        taxRate /= 100;
      }
      var Sales_tax = subTotal * taxRate;

      var Total = subTotal * (taxRate + 1);

      $("#sales_tax").val(Sales_tax);
      $("#total").val(Total);
```

Comment: Please explain what the issues are.  As the question states, this is apparently homework (an assignment), or something of the like.  So also on that note, providing a complete solution to them is probably not the best thing to do.

Comment: sure I will add explanations in a while.